# What is the difference between using "()" and not using it in object definition?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

As you see below I define a class named `Person` with two members named `age` and `name`:

```
>>> class person:
    age = None
    name = None
```

then I define two object of this class as below:

```
>>> p1 = person
>>> p2 = person()
```

My question is what is the difference between `p1` and `p2`:

```
>>> p1
<class __main__.person at 0x0328FF80>
>>> p2
<__main__.person instance at 0x03273738>
>>>
```

They act equal:

```
>>> p1.age = 19
>>> p1.name = "Steve"
>>> p2.age = 20
>>> p2.name = "Jimme"
>>> p1.age
19
>>> p1.name
'Steve'
>>> p2.age
20
>>> p2.name
'Jimme'
>>>
```

Comment: `p1 = person` does **not** instantiate an object of a class. It assigns another name to the class itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Person` is a class. The expression `Person()` creates an instance of that class. So the difference between `p1` and `p2` is that `p1` is a reference to a *class*, and `p2` is an reference to an *instance* of that class. For example, you can use `p1` to instantiate other `Person` objects:

```
>>> p3 = p1()
>>> p3
<__main__.person instance at 0x10c9403f8>
```

If `person` had instance variables you might observe a difference. In your case, `name` and `age` are class variables. That means they are shared by all instances of the `person` class. It is unlikely this is the behaviour you want.

```
>>> p1 = person
>>> p2 = person()
>>> p1.name = 'bob'
>>> p1.name
'bob'
>>> p2.name
'bob'
>>> person.name
'bob'
```

As you can see, all new `person`s now are called `bob`.

Here's a slightly more reasonable `person` class, that can still be instantiated with empty `()`:

```
class Person(object):
  def __init__(self, name='bill', age=42):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
```

Here, `name` and `age` are *instance* variables.

```
>>> p1 = Person
>>> p2 = Person()
>>> p3 = Person('fred')
>>> p1.name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'Person' has no attribute 'name'
>>> p2.name
'bill'
>>> p3.name
'fred'
```

Comment: Perhaps if an example was given where the class had an `__init__` method would make it more clear what was going on.  That is what was missing from the OP's test class to make the difference obvious.

Comment: @SethMMorton I added an example, although I don't know how much it clarifies things, because one can still say `p1.name = 'something'` or `p2.foobar = 42`. Explaining that is probably beyond the scope of this post.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that if you were to use `p1 = Person; p2 = Person`, and then change the name of one of them, it would change the other one's name too. So it wouldn't even work